# How to run unittest with IDEA dart plugin?

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, dart

IDEA dart-plugin provide an option as "run as DartUnit":

[image]

I wrote a simple test in **unit.dart**:

```
import "package:unittest/unittest.dart";

main() {
    test("aaa", () {
        expect(1, 1);
    });
}
```

Then I choose this `DartUnit` option. But it reports I misses something:

```
Error running Test: unit.dart: Missing library statement in unit.dart
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason: I need to declare a library in the code, any name is OK.

```
library aLirary;

...
```

Comment: Do you know why this is?